# How can I read the API authentication data from a file using Python?

Tags: python, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I am having trouble with a "Bad Authentication" error when reading my API keys from a file as such:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import tweepy

#open a file called "keys" with keys and tokens for Twitter separated by newlines
keyFile = open('keys', 'r')
consumer_key = keyFile.readline()
consumer_secret = keyFile.readline()
access_token = keyFile.readline()
access_token_secret = keyFile.readline()
keyFile.close()
print "consumer key: " + consumer_key
print "consumer secret: " + consumer_secret
print "access token: " + access_token
print "access token secret: " + access_token_secret

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
```

If I manually set my keys, like with `consumer_key = "xxx"`, it works fine. Any tips on why is doesn't work when reading from file? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out Python was reading the newline characters as well. The solution was to strip the hidden characters with rstrip():

`consumer_key = keyFile.readline().rstrip()`

Comment: Yeah, I was having the same problem too. I tried `consumer_key = f.readline()[:-1]` but that wasn't doing the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`keys.txt` file has 4 lines including `consumer_key`, `consumer_secret`, `access_token` and `access_token_secret` each separately in a line so we first read all the lines in the `keys.txt` file with `readlines` method. We would need to use `.rstrip()` in order to remove the unwanted `\n` from end of each string (or other possible unwanted characters). It is a good practice to keep these information in `keys.txt` file and add the name of `keys.txt` file in `.gitignore` when pushing your project to `GitHub` so that others won't hack your account when you push your code to `GitHub`.

```
keys_file = open("keys.txt")
lines = keys_file.readlines()
consumer_key = lines[0].rstrip()
consumer_secret = lines[1].rstrip()
access_token = lines[2].rstrip()
access_token_secret = lines[3].rstrip()
```

Comment: It would be better to add some clarification and not only code snippet, and for better understanding.